# Permission to loading into kernel

Tags: android, permissions

Is there a permission in the Android system which would allow me to perform specific operations like install drivers?

Something like copy it somewhere on the system and load it into the kernel using `insmod` command?

Answer (score 2):

No. Most things that require 'root' privileges on standard linux systems are not allowed for Android applications (unless the phone is rooted).